# Python 3.6 is installed two times as python3 and python3.6: can I remove one of them? How can i do it?

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

Ubuntu 18.04, from my terminal

```
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8

~$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.8

~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

~$ which python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6


~$ ls -la /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3637680 nov 28  2018 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 nov 28  2018 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     385 apr 11  2018 /usr/bin/python2-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     389 apr 11  2018 /usr/bin/python2-pasteurize
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 ott 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4571576 gen 14  2019 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 gen 14  2019 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4571576 gen 14  2019 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 gen 14  2019 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 ott 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 ott 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 ott 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

it seems to me that I have python 3 installed two times.

Can I remove one of the installations? Which one can I remove? How can I verify that the operation doesn't affect the system? (I read that is highly  discouraged the disinstallation of python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in your question “`/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6`”, `python3` is a symlink to `python3.6`. It uses next to no space. `Python3` will be a link to the latest `python3.x` than you have installed.

You could remove the link, but don't you will break something.

It may appear that you have two pythons installed
`/usr/bin/python3.6` and `/usr/bin/python3.6m`. However not that the link could is `2` (the 2nd field). If you do `ls -lia /usr/bin/python*`, then you will see that they both have the same inode number (they are the same file, but two different names). Some programs look at their names when run, and change behaviour based on their name.

## Conclusion

There is no evidence of more than one python 3 being installed.

Answer (score 3):

Having python3 and python3.6 in the `/usr/bin` directory doesn't mean that you have two installations of Python. Usually actual python interpreter is installed in  `/usr/bin/pythonX.Y` where X in major version and Y is minor version.

In your case you actually have two versions of Python3.6 installed: `/usr/bin/python3.6` and `/usr/bin/python3.6m`. `/usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3m` are just symlinks to executables as I mentioned before.

StackOverflow topic covers the difference between these two versions: [Difference between python3 and python3m executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675865/difference-between-python3-and-python3m-executables)

I don't know why you have python3m installed, but I wouldn't remove python3 from the system if you haven't installed it by yourself.

Comment: i edited my question with the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/python*`, maybe you're right, can you confirm?

Comment: @marco_autiero I updated answer